# Having difficulty matching regex to filter method

Tags: javascript

Doing a challenge, went a much more complicated route than the solution provided, but now I want to solve the regex filter issue I've stumbled upon.

Everything works fine until the the second to last line of the `currentFileExt()` function. I originally planned on using map, but after looking through similar StackOverflow solutions I figured `.filter()` is more appropriate. Sadly, I can't seem to get the filter to check against the regex I provided.

Perhaps it's a misunderstanding on my part, but I am using the filter to match each string element of the split `toArr` array, if it matches the regex it should get filtered. Unfortunately, that doesnt appear to be happening.

```
function findFileName(fileName) {
    let detect = (fileName.match(/\.+/g)) ? currentFileExt() : alert("Please enter");
    return detect;

    function currentFileExt() {
        let toArr = fileName.split('');
        let fileExtArr = [];
        // let validCharacter = new RegExp(/\.[a-z]+/, 'g');
        let validCharacter = /\.[a-z]+/;
        fileExtArr = toArr.filter( (element) => { element.match(validCharacter) });
        return fileExtArr.join('');
    }  
}

findFileName('java.java');
```

Comment: Filter removes unmatched elements. So `['a', 'b'].filter(i => i === 'a') // ['a']`. Also you're splitting on every character with `split('')`, looks like it should be `split('.')` maybe? Otherwise if its a single character then your regular expression seems to be looking for more than one character. Also, split will remove the split character. You can probably do it all in a single regexp without splitting also:
`fileName.match(/\.\w+$/i)`. Not totally sure what your expected inputs and outputs are.

Comment: @justin.m.chase you're right regarding just splitting by the period, the solution they provided actually was much simpler and just popped off what was split. My overly complicated approach however split the whole thing into an array and now I want to filter out everything following the '.' . It's dumb, but I'd like to solve this new problem I made for myself.

Comment: why are you splitting the filename ? after filter each element of toArr has exactly length of `1` and your regex is trying to match two characters `\.` and `[a-z]+`. which returns null everytime in filter

Comment: ok well then just look for the lastIndexOf the dot maybe, and then slice off the end. `a = 'a.b.c'; i = a.lastIndexOf('.'); return a.slice(i + 1)`

Comment: RegExp specifically works on a string, if you split it into an array then you need to use array operations on individual characters

Comment: Thanks, I'll put this function on the back burner. I feel I went down a rabbit hole without having a complete understanding of the tools I was using. I'll give it another go and get more comfortable with regex/filter etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues is that your filter callback function isn't returning any values. In order to do that with an arrow function with a body, you need to add a `return` keyword or better yet just remove the body.

`String#match` is also probably not the method you're looking for since that returns an array of matches or null if there are no matches. If you use `RegExp#test`, you will get a boolean depending if the string matches the regular expression.

So maybe the following will suit your needs:

```
function findFileName(fileName) {
    const detect = (fileName.match(/\.+/g)) ? currentFileExt() : alert("Please enter");
    return detect;

    function currentFileExt() {
        const toArr = fileName.split('');
        const validCharacter = /\.[a-z]+/;
        const fileExtArr = toArr.filter(element => validCharacter.test(element));
        return fileExtArr.join('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the function still doesn't work (which I don't really care about at this point, my function was an overly complicated mess anyway), but I do appreciate the hints and effort. Have a best answer and thumbs up.